# grails - custom sorting on the hasMany relations?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

i'm working on a multilingual grails application.

here is an example of my implementation of the multilingual feature:

the language domain

```
class Language {
    String name
   .....
}


class Category { 
    static hasMany = [translations : CategoryTranslation]
    ....
}


class CategoryTranslation {

    String name
    String description

    Language lang
    static belongsTo = [category:Category]

}
```

So category hasMany translations , 1 translation for each language , i want to sort categories by name , but the name is an attribute of the CategoryTranslation domain

what is the best way to implement sorting on the hasMany relations  ?

---

EDIT :

the problem is that i have for each category multiple translations , example ,

cat1 --> have 3 translations ( arabic , english , and French )

cat2 --> have 3 translations ( arabic , english , and French )

cat3 --> have 3 translations ( arabic , english , and French )

```
def categoriesSortedByArabicName = Category.list(sort: "arabicName");
def categoriesSortedByEnglishName = Category.list(sort: "englishName");
```

first I thought to use , a transient property for each language but this method dont work with sort  because the Hibernate translates the request to be processed with the database, and database simply doesn’t know what the field "arabicName" is anyway.

now i will try to  add transient property using formula in static mapping

Comment: hasMany is on `translations`, and you want to sort categories. Question is not clear. Can you please rephrase last two lines?

Comment: category hasMany translations , 1 translation for each language , i want to sort categories by english name , the name is an attribute of the CategoryTranslation domain

Answer (score 1):

Associations are `Set` by default. You have to use `SortedSet` to maintain an order:

```
import java.util.SortedSet

class Category { 
    SortedSet translations
    static hasMany = [translations : CategoryTranslation]
}

//implement Comparable
class CategoryTranslation implements Comparable {
    String name
    String description
    Language lang

    static belongsTo = [category:Category]

    int compareTo(obj) {
        obj.name <=> this.name
    }
}
```

With Grails 2.4 (latest milestone) you get Groovy 2.3.0-SNAPSHOT, where you can use [**`@Sortable`**](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.3.0-beta-1/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Sortable.html) AST transformation for `CategoryTranslation` as below:

```
import groovy.transform.Sortable

@Sortable(includes='name')
class CategoryTranslation {
    String name
    String description
    Language lang

    static belongsTo = [category:Category]
}
```

Comment: It is still a grey area of me with what you have in edit. Answer is based on your comment. You want to sort on the name (which is in english) present in CategoryTranslation, right?

Comment: yes , like you said i want to sort on the name present in CategoryTranslation , but in CategoryTranslation i dont have only the english names , but i have also other languages, one instance of CategoryTranslation for each language , i want to sort All the Categories based on the name and the language, so if i sort on the name , only translation with language = english should be taken into consideration , ( something like this : Category.findAll([sort:"englishName"]) to sort only based on translations with name = to english )

Comment: Is this still a grey area? @HamilaMohamedAmine